# Fill with a user specified colormap a `plot[cycle]`

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have something like the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [draw=gray, ultra thick]plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {
(6+0.3,-0.5) (6+0.3,1.5-0.2)(7+0.3,1.5)(7+0.3,2.5)(6+0.3,2.5+0.2) (6+0.3,5.5)(6+0.1,5.5)(6+0.1,-0.5)
};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

that creates something like a Gaussian (yeah, its not, and neither is intended to be, but kind of looks like one).

How can I fill this figure with a gradient that is higher in the highest point? I can make it user defined, no need for maths, e.g. Lighter (or darker) part to be on `y=2`.

Comment: You can add `top color=yellow,bottom color=black` to draw options\

Comment: @percusse Can you add more? E.g `medium color`?

Comment: yes it is called `middle color`. More options are in the PGF/TikZ manual about shadings.

Comment: I'm on the phone now. If anyone else doesn't write it, I'll make a MWE later in the day :)

Comment: @percusse But that only works for a single "direction" shading. I can not say `top,middle,bottom` it will ignore middle

Comment: Yes the order matters, `middle` should come last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the default shadings here which is automatically enabled if you use `top color=yellow` (or `bottom`). If you want to use a middle color you have to declare it after these keys since the other two overwrites the middle color. This is because you can use only one key to enable a shading and they automatically fill the middle color by interpolation. From the manual

> Note: Since both `top color` and `bottom color` change the `middle color`, this option should be given last if all of these options need to be given

In this case the output is

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [draw=gray, ultra thick,top color=yellow,bottom color=black,middle color=white]
    plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {
(6+0.3,-0.5) 
(6+0.3,1.5-0.2)
(7+0.3,1.5)
(7+0.3,2.5)
(6+0.3,2.5+0.2)
(6+0.3,5.5)
(6+0.1,5.5)
(6+0.1,-0.5)
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]